# Simple module system (callbacks)

Tags: c++

I'm trying to make a simple module engine, but I don't really know where to start, I want to create something like this:

```
int awesomefunction() {
 // do something here
    execute_awesomefunction_callbacks_here();
 // some more stuff
}
```

The *execute_awesomefunction_callbacks_here();* would execute all the functions that are in a std::vector

Any ideas on how to achieve this? Or are there any better ways of doing this?

Comment: Observer design pattern?

Comment: Laughed at naming sense. *Uh, cant delete my comment from mobile phone*

Answer (score 3):

You could implement it with an `std::vector` of `std::function`. The only constraint is that all the function objects must have  compatible return type and argument types.

```
class Publisher {

 public:
  void registerSubscriber(std::function<int(int, double)> callback) {
    callbacks_.push_back(callback);
  int executeAwesomeFunction() const {
    // loop over vector calling each function object.
  }
 private:
  std::vector<std::function<double(int,double)>> callbacks_;
}
```

This requires C++11 support, but you can achieve the same using [boost::function](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/doc/html/function.html)

Comment: are you sure one can inherit std::function? I thought no because it only contains typedefs, and also no virtual destructor ?

Comment: @StephaneRolland hmm, I never said anything about inheriting from `std::function`.

Comment: all my fault, i was mistaking with std::unary_function and std::binary_function of C++03. I've not really used C++11 std::function for now.